# Aggregate using values within a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

|  | Region | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AB | 1 |
| 1 | AB | 1 |
| 2 | AB | 2 |
| 3 | BC | 3 |
| 4 | BC | 4 |
| 5 | BC | 5 |

How do I turn this dataframe to the below where the distinct values of the region are columns and the distinct value of each month are the rows. The values are the sum of count of all stance of the region/month combination. Since I have a the list of Region and Month I can also specify them as a list, as long as it gives me the view below.

I used `df.groupby(['Region', 'Month'], as_index=True).agg({"Month": "count"})` however the layout is different where the month is a column instead of the layout below.

|  | AB | BC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JAN | 2 | 0 |
| FEB | 1 | 0 |
| MAR | 0 | 1 |
| APR | 0 | 1 |
| MAY | 0 | 1 |
| JUN | 0 | 0 |
| JUL | 0 | 0 |
| AUG | 0 | 0 |
| SEP | 0 | 0 |
| OCT | 0 | 0 |
| NOV | 0 | 0 |
| DEC | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

```
df_out = pd.crosstab(df['Month'], df['Region'])
df_out.index = df_out.index.map(dict(enumerate(calendar.month_abbr)))
df_out = df_out.reindex(calendar.month_abbr, fill_value=0)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
Region  AB  BC
Month         
         0   0
Jan      2   0
Feb      1   0
Mar      0   1
Apr      0   1
May      0   1
Jun      0   0
Jul      0   0
Aug      0   0
Sep      0   0
Oct      0   0
Nov      0   0
Dec      0   0
```

Let's try this:

```
import calendar

indx = [m.upper() for m in calendar.month_abbr[1:]]

pd.crosstab(df['Month'], df['Region']).reindex(indx, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
Region  AB  BC
Month         
JAN      2   0
FEB      1   0
MAR      0   1
APR      0   1
MAY      0   1
JUN      0   0
JUL      0   0
AUG      0   0
SEP      0   0
OCT      0   0
NOV      0   0
DEC      0   0
```

Details:

Use `pd.crosstab` to get counts per month by region, and using the calendar library we can get a list of all month abbreviations in order and fill in the missing value of the resultant dataframe from pd.crosstab.

Comment: Thank you, my month values are actually numerical (i.e. 1 = JAN , 2 = FEB). Do I use a replace function to replace the values first (so they match exactly with the calendar values) for it to work?

Comment: @BKB I am sorry, but I don't understand.    Can you provide the sample input in the format you working with.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I've updated the original post - the month is actually in number format instead of alphabetical.

Comment: @BKB See update